# Difference between DeviceWatcher and BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher class and Timeout property

Tags: uwp, timeout, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

I had built a windows 10 application that watch for a specific advertisement and connect with it.

I used the example ["BluetoothLE" from "Windows-universal-samples"](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs) with a little bit edits. In this example they used "DeviceWatcher " Class.

But I'm now trying to add timeout to disconnect after a specific period. 
I found this property: OutOfRangeTimeout  which belongs to BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher Class.

Now I'm  confused what are the differences between "DeviceWatcher" AND "BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher"?

And is there a way to add "timeout" using DeviceWatcher Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big difference between the "DeviceWatcher " Class and the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` Class. The deviceWacher is on system-level; meaning You have to add the device first in Windows Settings before it can be found. This also means that the device is always present in the Windows.Devices.Enumeration, unless you remove it from  Windows Settings. It takes a long time for the device watcher to complete. Also to make a well-working application you will have to implement all of the added, removed, and updated events to be notified when there are device additions, removals or updates. If an app handles only the added event, it will not receive an update if a device is added to the system after the initial device enumeration completes.

The `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` only listens to BLE-devices that send advertisements and that are in reach. If you set the `scanMode` to active, the watcher tries to get all information on the device, like name, capabilities, ble-Address, Services advertisement payload, etc. Setting it for `scanMode` passive, the watcher listens only for the device using name and Ble-address, which is faster.

The scanning time depends only on the number of devices in reach and their advertising interval. The `OutOfRangeTimeout` refers to the `BluetoothSignalStrengthFilter` that decides if a device is out of reach.

As for the timeOut to disconnect:

Bluetooth LE devices APIs do not provide direct control over the connection to the device. Instead, the Bluetooth-stack will disconnect the device after a one-second timeout if there are no outstanding references to it. So you have to use a timer to set your timeOut and close and dispose of the device!

Comment: >  The OutOfRangeTimeout refers to the BluetoothSignalStrengthFilter that decides if a device is out of reach.

But what does it do when it decides the device is out of reach?  BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received event fires based on advertising packets received.

Comment: @ Frank Schwieterman,
You should ask this in a new question, but here is a short answer:
If  the advertising device  RSSI value is greater than or equal to InRangeThresholdInDBm and the  OutOfRangeTimeout has not expired. The device is considered in range. The RSSI reading will show the real value.
If If  the advertising device  RSSI values are less than or equal to the OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm, the timer is reset and when it expires the device is considered out of range. The RSSI reading will show a steady value of -127 until is in reach again.

Comment: @GrooverFromHolland I am trying out DeviceWatcher, and am not seeing the behavior you've described. The device I'm testing is a BLE motion sensor. It reports coordinates using the GATT profile. I haven't added it in Windows Settings. But unlike what you mentioned, DeviceWatcher does report both Added and Removed events as I turn the device on and off. For my application, I will need the device available at startup. If it's not available, the application should exit immediately. So scanning once at startup should be good enough for me. Would I get benefit from BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher?

Comment: @Gene Pavlovsky, The Windows.Devices.Enumeration query for Bluetooth devices(the  DeviceWatcher) does an active scan for proximately 30 seconds, then all scanning activities are cancelled, to prevent interference with other Bluetooth devices. 
After the scan, devices can be found via other means, such as a directed advertisement, through the whitelist, or an Advertisement Watcher,
The results are still delivered to the enumeration API(DeviceWatcher), but in a slower pace.
For longer scanning or even permanent scanning,  the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher is recommended.

Comment: @GrooverFromHolland Thanks for the info. So I already have working code based on DeviceWatcher. I only need to scan for device at startup - if it's not found, the program should exit. Would there be any benefit (e.g. reliability, scan speed) to modify the code to use BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher instead?